# Passing Json array value from codeigniter to Jquery calendar Error

Tags: php, jquery, json, codeigniter, calendar

I am trying to integrate Jquery calendar plugin with the codeigniter database and passing Json array what would be the mistake appreciate your help.

calendar.php in view

```
<script>
var unavailableDates = '<?php echo base_url() ?>Calr/getevent';

$('#calendar').availabilityCalendar(unavailableDates);
</script>
```

Controller Calr.php

```
public function getevent()
{
    $this->load->model(user/Calr_model/SelectAll);

}
```

Model Calr_model.php

```
function SelectAll()
{
    $sql = 'SELECT start_date,end_date,link FROM tbl_events';
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    // Fetch the result array from the result object and return it
    return $query->result();
}
```

have tried this function also in calr_model.php

```
function SelectAll()
{
$sql = 'SELECT start_date,end_date,link FROM tbl_events';
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
// Fetch the result array from the result object and return it
return $query->result();
$emparray = array();
while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
{
$emparray[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($emparray);
}
```

but json array values is not retrived from database,
static input for which is working in view like

calendar.php

```
<script>
var unavailableDates = [{start: '2015-08-31', end: '2015-09-05', title:'Event 1'} {start: '2015-09-11', end: '2015-09-15', title:'Event 2'},{start: '2015-09-15', end: '2015-09-23', title:'Event 3'},{start: '2015-10-01', end: '2015-10-07', title:'Event 4'}];
$('#calendar').availabilityCalendar(unavailableDates);
</script>
```

Regards,

Vinoth

Comment: since you are not returning json data

Comment: Vigneswaran S edited my question with another model function i tried

Answer (score 0):

You should have a better distinction between the model and the controller. A model should never echo anything. This is the job of the controller.

Your controller:

```
public function getevent()
{
  $this->load->model('Calr_model');
  $data = $this->Calr_model->SelectAll();
  echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Your model (be sure to rename the fields to the proper javascript names, saves you the trouble later):

```
function SelectAll()
{
  $sql = 'SELECT `start_date` AS `start`, `end_date` AS `end`, `link AS `title` FROM tbl_events';
  $query = $this->db->query($sql);
  return $query->result();
}
```

You could load this model-method on page load of the normal page. So you don't need another controller for this. If you use AJAX to retreive the data with a normal Ajax call and on success add the events to the calendar with

```
$.ajax({url: "/Calr/getevent/", success: function(result){
  $('#calendar').availabilityCalendar(result);
}});
```

Mind you, usually the calendar has an event when the calendar is done loading. Use that event to retreive the data via the Ajax function above, otherwise it may not work properly.